# Derivative of $\int_{-\infty}^{x}(z-x)f(z)\, dz$ with respect to $x$

Tags: integration, derivatives, random-variables

I am trying to apply the [Leibnitz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to the following problem:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^{x}(z-x)f(z)\, dz
$$
where $f(z)$ is the density function of random variable $Z$ (in contrast to the reference above, I use $z$ in place of $t$). I get
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^{x}(z-x)f(z)\, dz 
&= (x-x)f(x)\cdot 1 - (-\infty-x)f(-\infty)\cdot 0 + \int_{-\infty}^{x}(-f(z))\, dz \\
&= 0-\color{red}{(-\infty-x)f(-\infty)\cdot 0} - F(x)
\end{aligned}
where $F(\cdot)$ is the cumulative density function of the random variable $Z$.

**Questions:**

1. Is the derivation correct?
2. How do I deal with the expression in red?

---

P.S. I am also trying to solve a similar problem:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{\infty}(z-x)f(z)\, dz
$$
where I get
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x}^{\infty}(z-x)f(z)\, dz 
&= (\infty-x)f(\infty)\cdot 0 - (x-x)f(x)\cdot 1 + \int_{x}^{\infty}(-f(z))\, dz \\
&= \color{red}{(\infty-x)f(\infty)\cdot 0} - 0 - (1-F(x)).
\end{aligned}

Comment: HINT: $$\frac{\partial \left(\int_{-\infty }^x f(z) (z-x) \, dz\right)}{\partial x}=\int_{-\infty }^x -f(z) \, dz$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\int_{-\infty}^xzf(z)dz-x\int_{-\infty}^xf(z)dz\right]\\=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\int_{-\infty}^xzf(z)dz\right]-\frac{dx}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^xf(z)dz-x\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^xf(z)dz\\=xf(x)-\int_{-\infty}^xf(z)dz-xf(x)=-\int_{-\infty}^xf(z)dz=-F(x),$$where the first $=$ uses the product rule.

Comment: Thank you and +1. Could you also comment on whether the answer of the second problem (in the P.S.) is $-(1-F(x))$?

Comment: @RichardHardy That is the correct answer, but I recommend proving it with a strategy like the one in either existing answer, using $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^cg(z)dz=\color{blue}{-}g(x).$$

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not valid. Note that you are just trying to find $\dfrac d {dx} \left[\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{x} zf(z)dz-x\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(z)dz\right]$. The answer is $x(f (x))-x (f(x)) -\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(z)dz$ where I have used product rule for the second term. So your answer is indeed correct but your method is not.

Comment: Thank you and +1. Could you also comment on whether the answer of the second problem (in the P.S.) is $-(1-F(x))$?